# Margin on JTable with 1px border

Tags: java, swing, border, margin

I have `JTable` inside a `JScrollPane` inside a `JPanel` inside a `JFrame`. Normally the table or the scroll pane have a grey 1px-thick border. To add margin, I learned to use `EmptyBorder`, but this overrides the old border. Is there a way to keep the grey 1px-thick border and set a margin of 15px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember if the Border is defined on the tabel or the scrollpane. If you want the 15 pixels between the table and the scrollpane then you can try either of the following approaches:

1. add the `EmptyBorder` to the table
2. use a `CompoundBorder`. Use the `EmptyBorder` as the outer Border and use `scrollPane.getBorder()` as the inner border.

Or maybe you just want the EmptyBorder on the panel. I can't really tell you exact requirement. Anyway, you have enough information to play around. The trick to it just add the Border to the proper component.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED,2));
```

Comment: If I use `createLineBorder`, it creates a border with the specified color and the specified thickness. I want to keep the 1px-thick border AND have a margin.